# Two levels of authentication in ASP.Net Core Identity in 2021

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How can I manage two levels of authentication in Asp.Net Identity, where some (critical) functions can only be called when fully authenticatied - where some less critical ones can be called with less secure authentication?

Scenario:

The users can log in two ways:

- Via the usual username/password functionality (Full Auth)
- Via a short-lived URL token/one time password (Partial Auth)

Ideally, I can use something similar to the [Authorize(Roles=xxxxx)] attributes to easily decorate methods, that required full or partial auth. This would hopefully also take care of redirecting to Full Login page if partially authenticated.

How can this be accomplished in 2022?

The same question was asked in 2014 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401794/manage-2-levels-of-authentication-with-asp-net-identity-2-0) - but that is 8 years ago, and many things could have changed, so I think it is relevant to ask again.

Comment: How about using [authorization policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) ? The idea was when fully login, we grant an additional claim like `Fully`. Then we assign default authorization policy to just required authenticated user, but for some sensitive one, decorate the action with `[Authorize(Policy=xxx)]`, which required authenticated user and the extra `Fully` claim ? The implementation would be vary as authentication mechanism.

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. Thanks, I will look into that. :)